# What are the differences between Paizo's Pathfinder 2e GM screens?

Tags: pathfinder-2e

When looking at the Paizo store, there were 3 different GM screens available at the same price (all in [the “Other Accessories” section](https://paizo.com/store/pathfinder/accessories/other)):

- [GM screen](https://paizo.com/products/btq01zol?Pathfinder-GM-Screen)
- [Advanced GM screen](https://paizo.com/products/btq023gi?Pathfinder-Advanced-GM-Screen)
- [Portrait Advanced GM screen](https://paizo.com/products/btq023gk?Pathfinder-Advanced-GM-Screen)

There is a [section in the archives of Nethys](https://2e.aonprd.com/GMScreen.aspx) called GM Screen.

I am under the impression that:

- The Advanced GM screen contains information from the Game-master’s guide that the main GM screen doesn’t have.
- The contents of the GM screens is as listed on the GM screen section section linked above.

I would like to confirm that my assumptions are correct and ask the following:

- Does the Advanced GM screen omit any information that is present in the basic GM screen?
- How do the two advanced GM screens differ?
- Exactly what AoN GM screen rules are omitted in which screens?
- Are there any other differences that define the sort of GM each screen is suited for?

Comment: There's one more, you're missing the portrait normal GM screen (https://paizo.com/products/btq01zon).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The Advanced GM screen contains information from the Game-master’s guide that the main GM screen doesn’t have.

Correct (a list is below).

> The contents of the GM screens is as listed on the GM screen section section linked above.

Correct, and then some. The AoN screen has things that aren't on either of the physical ones. (A list is below)

> Does the Advanced GM screen omit any information that is present in the basic GM screen?

Yes:

- Basic/Special Action list
- Skill Action List (lists actions each skill has and what level of proficiency is required)
- Hero Point usage
- Specific Skill DCs (such as the DC for identifying a magic item or recall knowledge)
- Turn Order and Icon Key
- Exploration Activities

> How do the two advanced GM screens differ?

AFAIK content wise they are the same, but I don't own the portrait version so I can't validate that.

> Exactly what AoN GM screen rules are omitted in which screens?

What's missing from each screen is in one of those lists already. The following things are on neither screen but are on AoN:

- Earn Income table
- Temperature table
- Weapon traits table  (what each trait does)

> Are there any other differences that define the sort of GM each screen is suited for?

The Advanced GM screen includes rules from the Gamemastery guide that the standard screen does not:

- Creature Numbers (for creating monsters)
- Hazard Numbers (for creating hazards)
- Victory Points (a subsystem)
- Reputation Points (another subsystem)

If you are using these systems on the fly, this will be very useful. If you are not, they are not useful at all. In the case of Creature and Hazard numbers, on the fly means "you are making up a creature or hazard in the middle of a session". If you are making a creature in your prep, this information doesn't need to be on the DM screen as you will have its final numbers already.

The standard GM screen covers things that are always useful, and especially for a newer DM are things you will be looking up frequently. Some of them get easier to remember later and if the list above of what's removed from the Advanced screen is things you already know anyway, then the Advanced screen will probably serve you well.

But if you are looking those things up frequently, the standard screen is going to be used more often as a reference.

Comment: +1 - "the standard screen is going to be used more often as a reference". I have neither GM screen but I keep a table of DC's open in my OneNote page at all times, it's been very useful over the year and half I've been GMing. On the other hand, I've yet to try inventing a creature or hazard on the fly (granted, I'm running an AP; I might if I was homebrewing).

Comment: @ESCE I ran a homebrew campaign until recently and I almost never invented a monster on the fly. It's a useful set of rules to have, but IMO it's going to be very rarely used in the middle of a session, and I can just pull out the book if that actually happens. I look at the standard DM screen at least 10 times every session.

Comment: Why would the archives of nethys's GM screen section containn rules that are omited in all screens?

Comment: @SuperS Space, I'd guess. The physical screens are constrained by their physical size, and things like the temperature and earn income tables are space intensive. Archives of Nethys has no such limitation and thus is free to add whatever it wants to that page.